# uicontextmenu inaccessible when using pcolor and contourf (MATLAB R2014b)

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am not especially experienced with MATLAB so this might be a dumb question, but I would appreciate any help that can be given.

I have some code that creates some axes, assigns a uicontextmenu to said axes, and then plots a graph of the user's choosing on the axes. The uicontextmenu is accessible by right-clicking on the graphs (as it should be) in every plot case it needs to EXCEPT for pcolor and contourf. Why would this be? Is there any way I can get around this?

Through extensive debugging I have found that the uicontextmenu is accessible until the pcolor (or contourf) functions are called and then it disappears. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** As requested, example code below. If you use pcolor the uicontextmenu won't appear and if you use plot then it will. I think it has something to do with the data the cursor is highlighting. If your cursor right clicks on plotted data, nothing appears in both. But why is this?

```
axes;

stuff = uicontextmenu('Parent',ancestor(axes,'figure'));
stuffm = uimenu('Parent',stuff,'Label','Change something');
set(axes,'uicontextmenu',stuff);

x = randn(10);
y1=randn(10,1);
y2=randn(10,1);


plot(y1,y2)
%pcolor(x)
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pcolor` function creates a `surface` graphics object which has its own `uicontextmenu` property. You have to set it after the `pcolor` returns the surface handle:

```
h= pcolor(x);
set(h,'uicontextmenu',stuff);
```

Comment: I have a new, slightly different question. Why does this not work with contourf? 

`axes;

stuff = uicontextmenu('Parent',ancestor(axes,'figure'));
stuffm = uimenu('Parent',stuff,'Label','Change something');

x = randn(10);
y1=randn(10,1);
y2=randn(10,1);


%plot(y1,y2)
h = contourf(x);
set(h,'uicontextmenu',stuff);`

Comment: I have added a new question since they are obviously not equivalent, as I had assumed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364252/how-to-set-uicontextmenu-for-contourf-matlab2014b