# How to set uicontextmenu for contourf (MATLAB2014b)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

Originally [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333293/uicontextmenu-inaccessible-when-using-pcolor-and-contourf-matlab-r2014b) why pcolor and contourf don't work with this method, and I assumed they were symptoms of the same problem. This is not true, hence the new question.

Why does this not work with contourf? (and how do i get it to work?)

```
axes; 
stuff = uicontextmenu('Parent',ancestor(axes,'figure')); 
stuffm = uimenu('Parent',stuff,'Label','Change something'); 
x = randn(10); 
h = contourf(x);
% pcolor works! contourf does not
%h = pcolor(x) 
set(h,'uicontextmenu',stuff);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign the context menu to the wrong object.

The first output of `contourf`, as noted in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html), is the "contour matrix", you want the handle to the object:

> `[M,c] = contourf(___)` returns the contour matrix and the contour object `c`. **Use `c` to set properties after displaying the contour plot.**

So just change your code as follows:

```
[~,h] = contourf(x); % 2nd output is the object handle
set(h,'uicontextmenu',stuff);
```

Result is a working context menu:

[image: context menu]

Note you were also creating axes twice, I think the 2nd time is unintentional when creating the context menu, fix this like so:

```
ax = axes; % assign new axes to variable for later use
stuff = uicontextmenu('Parent',ancestor(ax,'figure')); % use ax, not new axes
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! MATLAB is not my main language but I'm working on it for a short while. The double axes thing is a mistake I made whilst abstracting the problem from a bigger code.

Comment: @jgd10 No worries, some less common plots have quirks like this, `pie` is even worse (but then so are pie charts!).

Comment: I don't think there's ever a good reason to use a pie chart... unless you want to make pac-man for some reason